# Routing between same subnet

Tags: networking

I have 2 routers

Router A connected to 10.1.0.0/8
Router B connected to 10.2.0.0/8

and a link between Router A and Router B
does it work ?
or I have to assign a different network id like /9 prefix because both networks have the 
same network id?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usuful to read: [http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `10.1.0.0/8` and `10.2.0.0/8` are the same subnet. If you want to route between them you'll need to change them to `10.1.0.0/16` and `10.2.0.0/16`. Then there's also the matter of making sure all the routes are correct in your routers.